# Code to clear DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkbox, textbox

See code below:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvStatus.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
            {
               c.Value = "";
            }
        }
```

Pretty simple, clears all the values. But I need to make some modifications to it and don't know how to go along.

I want it to clear all the values, except for the first cell in every column. Also, some cells contain checkboxes and not textboxes, how can I make a check for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvStatus.Rows) {
       if (r.Index == 0) {
           continue;
        }
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells) {                    
                if c.OwningColumn is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) {
                    continue;
                }
                c.Value = "";
            }
        }
```